# Adding Secrets in database onelogin

Tags: onelogin

Is there is a method through which we can add secrets such as user/pass the shell or ssh key or ssl certificates?

For example, if we add in onelogin a database, how can we add the credentials for db in onelogin?

Can you please provide us with a guide if such an option is possible?

Comment: I don't think OneLogin supports DB Connections as of now. You can add Active Directory, LDAP and other HRMS but not DB

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Secure Notes" feature.

https://onelogin.service-now.com/support?id=kb_article&sys_id=9ff95543db109700d5505eea4b96199c